# Express how to express cartesian electric field vectors in terms of spherical electric field components

Tags: electromagnetism, scattering, classical-electrodynamics, coordinate-systems, spherical-harmonics

I'm working on Mie scattering from a dielectric sphere. I have expressions for electric fields in terms of $E_{r}, E_{\theta}, E_{\phi}$ however now I would like to visualize these on cartesian planes $ E_{x}, E_{y}, E_{z}$. I am aware of the well known coordinate transformations

$ x=\rho sin(\phi)cos(\theta)$

$ y=\rho sin(\phi)sin(\theta)$

$ z=\rho cos(\phi)$

But i'm confused in how to get an explicit equation since there seems to be contribution to $E_x$ from all of $E_{\rho}, E_{\theta}, E_{\phi}$

Thanks for any insight/help

Answer (score 2):

The unitary vectors of the spherical coordinate system can be written in terms of the vectors of the cartesian coordinate system as

\begin{eqnarray}
\hat{\mathbf{\rho}} &=& \sin\theta\cos\phi \hat{\mathbf{x}} + \sin\theta\sin\phi \hat{\mathbf{y}} + \cos\theta\hat{\mathbf{z}} \\
\hat{\mathbf{\theta}} &=& \cos\theta\cos\phi \hat{\mathbf{x}} + \cos\theta\sin\phi \hat{\mathbf{y}} - \sin\theta\hat{\mathbf{z}} \\
\hat{\mathbf{\phi}} &=& -\sin\phi \hat{\mathbf{x}} + \cos\phi \hat{\mathbf{y}} 
\end{eqnarray}

The electric field written as

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbf{E} &=& E_\rho \hat{\mathbf{\rho}} + E_\theta \hat{\mathbf{\theta}} + E_\phi \hat{\mathbf{\phi}} \\
&=& E_\rho(\sin\theta\cos\phi \hat{\mathbf{x}} + \sin\theta\sin\phi \hat{\mathbf{y}} + \cos\theta\hat{\mathbf{z}}) +\\ && E_\theta(\cos\theta\cos\phi \hat{\mathbf{x}} + \cos\theta\sin\phi \hat{\mathbf{y}} - \sin\theta\hat{\mathbf{z}}) +\\
&&  E_\phi(-\sin\phi \hat{\mathbf{x}} + \cos\phi \hat{\mathbf{y}} ) \\
&=& \hat{\mathbf{x}}(E_\rho\sin\theta\cos\phi + E_\theta \cos\theta\cos\phi - E_\phi\sin\phi) + \\
&& \hat{\mathbf{y}}(E_\rho\sin\theta\sin\phi + E_\theta\cos\theta\sin\phi + E_\phi\cos\phi) +\\
&&\hat{\mathbf{z}}(E_\rho\cos\theta - E_\theta\sin\theta) \\
&=& E_x\hat{\mathbf{x}} + E_y\hat{\mathbf{y}} + E_z\hat{\mathbf{z}}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Good answer - would benefit from having a diagram.